# Bash: how to simplify autocompletion of custom created functions by using the already available bash-completion functions?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

How can I reuse the completion functions that already exist inside `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` into my own custom functions, without having to write another function just to build the list of possible completions?

---

If the question isn't clear, take this example:

**• I created a function on my `.bashrc`:**

```
function gitdelbranch {
    git branch --delete ${1} && git push origin --delete ${1}
}
```

**• I'm already sourcing `. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`** on my `.bashrc`

**• Now, I want to be able to autocomplete my `gitdelbranch` function with the same options that `git branch -d` would give me.**

**• Looking inside** `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git:599`**, I can see that there is already a function that completes local branches, called `__git_heads()`**:

```
[...]
# Lists branches from the local repository.
# 1: A prefix to be added to each listed branch (optional).
# 2: List only branches matching this word (optional; list all branches if
#    unset or empty).
# 3: A suffix to be appended to each listed branch (optional).
__git_heads ()
[...]
```

> Also, another trick I learned while researching this: if I type on my shell `git branch -d`, press `<Tab>`, and then run `complete -p git`, I can see the whole complete command that was used for that *(you really have to run it once before it works)*:
>
> `complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git`

---

However, no matter what I try, I can't get to autocomplete my custom function with a single command, like `complete -o [...] -F __[...] gitdelbranch`.

**Question is: Why is that? Is there any way around it or do I really have to write a new, custom completion function, build the options list and COMMREPLY, just to get the behaviour I want?** It looks to me that this has to be possible, given that there's already a well written completion file on my system.

---

*As a bonus question: why doesn't even* `complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main gitdelbranch` *work, given that it's being used in the shell and working just fine with `git branch -d`?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git completion is quite easy to add to your own bash functions actually, for example, this little script autocompletes your git branches:

```
my_func () { return; }
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
__git_complete my_func __git_complete_refs
```

Now `my_func` has autocompletion for branch names.

Or like this you can have an alias `g` to `git` with working auto completion:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
alias g=git
__git_complete g __git_main
```

Look in the `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` file for all completions possible. The original file in the source code: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

There are a bunch of default complete functions, but they might not always do what you want, because they are made specially for git commands. In some cases you might want to make a custom auto complete function. Looking in the source code of the `git-completion.bash` you can figure stuff out. For example this auto complete function only completes local branch names:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
git_local_branches () {
    __gitcomp_direct "$(__git_heads "" "$cur" " ")"
}
my_func () { return; }
__git_complete my_func git_local_branches
```

Also see [this answer for](https://askubuntu.com/a/345150/230971) more info on how general bash completion works. Normally you would use the `complete` command, but Git created its own complete function `__git_complete`, which you should use for git completion.

Comment: Awesome! You have no idea how much time I spent trying to use `complete` *with* the functions inside `git-completion.bash`. Geez, I would have never guessed that git has its own functions if it weren't for you! It certainly makes it easier, that is, once you know about it :P

Comment: Hmm, any idea how could I complete _only local repositories_, like `__git_heads()` does? I tried pretty much every function and option available on the file, also found no decent documentation about git completion :|